# Clear field and type in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a qty field in code nead to clear '1' and type 2 but below code is inserting '21'.  Qty.clear is clearing the field but Qty.sendkeys is inserting '21'
The field will be like this
Quantity= - 1 +

```
WebElement Qty=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#quantity_11046"));     
Qty.clear();     
Qty.sendKeys("2")
```

Comment: Why not click on the + next to the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why this not works for you but I can suggest try other method using CTRL A (select) and then insert the value. Something like

```
Qty.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "2"))
```

Comment: Nice idea.  Great suggestion.   Or, create a clear field method that sends Keys.CONTROL-a  but it could be argued that using that "native accessor" is not as good as creating a pure-javascript non-native clearField method (and avoids using native Sendkeys).

Comment: Qty.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "2")). This worked. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Sree please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, thanks